# Thymeleaf: Including Fragment With Inner HTML In Variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jhipster

I want to do something like this:

```
<div th:insert="default_page :: entire_page">
    <p>
        Hello World
    </p> 
</div>

<html th:fragment="entire_page">
    // Somehow get <p> Hello World </p> in here
</html>
```

In other words, I want to include the inner html of a fragment include into the actual fragment itself.

Is this possible?

EDIT
To be clear, I don't want to hardcode the 'Hello World' into a variable and then send it to the fragment. I literally want to be able to put html inside the fragment caller and have it appear in the fragment.

The idea would be that I have a body div that I just want to fill up with content on each page if that makes sense.

Comment: I *think* what you're wanting to use is either fragment parameters or `th:with`.

Comment: Have you checked out thymeleaf layout dialect?  It's more in line with those kind of includes.